# How to capture data in unusual span tag with BS4?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on scraping a site for work and I cannot get Beautiful soup to scrape certain text between unusual tags.

I have searched simply for a span tag and it shows up in the results however I cannot get the specific words to show using re.compile shortly after.

This is a snipped of the html

```
ng-hide="col.isHidden || col.alwaysHide" ng-class="{&#39;td-content-title&#39;:col.isContentTitle}" responsive-table-cell="ctrl.getCellData(col, row)" aria-hidden="false"></td><!----><td ng-repeat="col in ctrl.tableConfig.columns" data-column-title="Result " ng-hide="col.isHidden || col.alwaysHide" ng-class="{&#39;td-content-title&#39;:col.isContentTitle}" responsive-table-cell="ctrl.getCellData(col, row)" aria-hidden="false"><span class="test-case-result status-2">Passed</span></td><!----><td ng-repeat="col in ctrl.tableConfig.columns" data-column-title="Approval " ng-hide="col.isHidden || col.alwaysHide" ng-class="{&#39;td-content-title&#39;:col.isContentTitle}" responsive-table-cell="ctrl.getCellData(col, row)" aria-hidden="false"><span class="test-case-approval-status status-1">Pending</span></td><!----><td ng-repeat="col in ctrl.tableConfig.columns" data-column-title="Time Left " ng-hide="col.isHidden || col.alwaysHide" ng-class="{&#39;td-content-title&#39;:col.isContentTitle}"
```

And this is the code that works at scraping all span tags

```
soup.find_all('span')
```

However when I use something like

```
soup.find_all('span', {re.compile('Passed|Failed')}):
```

It appears to give no results

I also tried

```
soup.find_all('span', {'test-case-result status-2': re.compile('Passed|Failed')})
```

Expected - All instances of Pass and Fail would be scraped

Actual - All attempts to scrape except for purely using span tage are appearing empty.

I'm sure this is simple and i'm missing something but i'm really struggling to get any further with the documentation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: add url to this page.

Comment: `soup.find_all('span', text=re.compile('Passed|Failed'))`

Comment: @furas I can't i'm afraid its for work so its behind a login wall

Comment: try `text=re.compile(...)` in `find_all()`

Comment: @furas You got it. Thanks so much. Can you type that as an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text=` in `find_all()`

```
soup.find_all('span', text=re.compile('Passed|Failed'))
```

Without `text=` it may use `regex` to search tag name.

Answer (score 0):

With bs 4.7.1 I would avoid regex and use `:contains` pseudo class

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
  ng-hide="col.isHidden || col.alwaysHide" ng-class="{&#39;td-content-title&#39;:col.isContentTitle}" responsive-table-cell="ctrl.getCellData(col, row)" aria-hidden="false"></td><!----><td ng-repeat="col in ctrl.tableConfig.columns" data-column-title="Result " ng-hide="col.isHidden || col.alwaysHide" ng-class="{&#39;td-content-title&#39;:col.isContentTitle}" responsive-table-cell="ctrl.getCellData(col, row)" aria-hidden="false"><span class="test-case-result status-2">Passed</span></td><!----><td ng-repeat="col in ctrl.tableConfig.columns" data-column-title="Approval " ng-hide="col.isHidden || col.alwaysHide" ng-class="{&#39;td-content-title&#39;:col.isContentTitle}" responsive-table-cell="ctrl.getCellData(col, row)" aria-hidden="false"><span class="test-case-approval-status status-1">Pending</span></td><!----><td ng-repeat="col in ctrl.tableConfig.columns" data-column-title="Time Left " ng-hide="col.isHidden || col.alwaysHide" ng-class="{&#39;td-content-title&#39;:col.isContentTitle}"
  '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

spans =  soup.select('span:contains(Passed),span:contains(Failed)')
print(spans)
```

Comment: Thanks @QHarr. What is the reason you would avoid regex? Is contains just easier to use?

Comment: It should be faster than regex in this case I believe